# Display only certain columns in results despite case statement in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d9e9697fcbe0f1c15cd81e01970d58c)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL,
    avg_price DECIMAL,
    normal_price DECIMAL
    
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(product, quantity, avg_price, normal_price)
VALUES 
('product_01', '800', '10', '10'),
('product_01', '300', '20', '90'),
('product_01', '200', '0', '50'),
('product_01', '500', '30', '80'),
('product_01', '600', '0', '60'),
('product_01', '400', '50', '40');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
product      |   quantity   |   final_price  |
-------------|--------------|----------------|--------------
product_01   |      800     |        10      |
product_02   |      300     |        20      |
product_03   |      200     |        50      |
product_04   |      500     |        30      |
product_05   |      600     |        60      |
product_06   |      400     |        50      |
```

---

I **only** want to **display** the column `quantity` and `final_price`.

However, I have to use a `CASE statement` in my query and the syntax from `postgresSQL` is forcing me to add the column `avg_price` and `normal_price` to the query in order to make the `CASE statement` work:

```
SELECT
iv.product AS product,
iv.avg_price AS avg_price,
iv.normal_price AS normal_price,
SUM(iv.quantity) AS quantity,
(CASE WHEN iv.avg_price = 0 THEN iv.normal_price ELSE iv.avg_price END) AS final_price
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

Not sure if this is possible in `postgresSQL` but is there a way to **only display** the **two** columns as in the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit `GROUP BY iv.product, iv.avg_price, iv.normal_price` instead of `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3`:

```
SELECT
iv.product AS product,
SUM(iv.quantity) AS quantity,
(CASE WHEN iv.avg_price = 0 THEN iv.normal_price ELSE iv.avg_price END) AS final_price
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY iv.product, iv.avg_price, iv.normal_price
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest aggregating by the expression itself:

```
SELECT iv.product AS product,
       SUM(iv.quantity) AS quantity,
       (CASE WHEN iv.avg_price = 0 THEN iv.normal_price ELSE iv.avg_price END) AS final_price
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY iv.product, final_price
ORDER BY 1;
```